# Internet very slow on new computer ,works fine on old computer

Tags: performance, internet-connection, connection

I just bought a new computer and it is extremely slow. It is showing that it is connected to the wireless server with full bars. The browsers open but are very slow to load, and can't play any music on spotify or watch anything on netflix.

My old computer is still working fine and the internet connection on it is fast, so I am ruling out that it is my internet connection.

I took my new computer to a friend's house and it is working perfect there but not at my house, which rules out that there is something wrong with the new computer.

What should be my next step?

Comment: well from your description, i take that it is the internet that is running slow on new comp...not the entire computer...
is your old comp also connecting over wifi?...if not, can you check the internet speed with some other wifi device?

Comment: It sounds like your internet connection is the problem.  I would contact your service provider.  My guess your trying to connect to a slower wireless internet ( i.e. 801.11b/a ).

Answer (score 0):

Let's be reasonable now. You took your computer to a different house and it runs faster? I find that hard to believe. Do you mean the internet is faster? Maybe it finished doing the automatic updates that were taking up the bandwith. If you do mean the internet is faster on your old computer try running a [speed test](https://secure.dslreports.com/stest/) on both computers and see if there's a difference. If there is, and both computers are connected to the internet in the same way (i.e. both using wireless g/n/etc.), perhaps there's a setting on the router (assuming you have one) that is favouring the old computer. Also maybe your old computer has a beter network interface card. If you mean the computer itself is faster at your friends house (e.g. starting up, loading programs etc.) it must have been a random coincidence.

Comment: yes...she does mean that the internet is faster...not the computer..

Comment: when i took my computer to a friends house it was connected to the wifi and the internet speed was very fast, but when i bring it back home it says the internet is connected but wont load any pages. my old computer is connected to the same router and is running fine. if the problem is in my router favouring the old computer how do i change that?

Comment: ive already done  ipconfig /release and renew and that didn't change anything

Comment: @nataliamegally try connecting it with an Ethernet cable. superuser.com really isn't the best place to answer these questions because to fix this requires more of discussion than a single answer. Try here http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/